# In Rails find what customers have ordered an item

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Is there a way in ruby to get results for which customers have ordered a particular item?  I have my models set up like this:

```
class Customer < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :order_items
has_many :products, :through => :order_items
end

class OrderItem < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :product
belongs_to :customer
end

class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :order_items
has_many :customers, :through => :order_items
belongs_to :category
end
```

Ideally I would like to be able to write something in ruby that would return what return an array of customers that have ordered a certain product.  Basically I want to write something like:

```
Customer.product.where(:name => "Widget").first
```

And have that work and return the first customer in the database that had ordered that product.  Essentially searching the name field of the product table, returning a product_id and then using that product_id to see which customer_ids are associated with it in the order_items table and use those customer_ids to return the fields in the customers table associated with those customer_ids

Comment: Do you want one customer, or all of them that have ordered the product?

Answer (score 1):

Search in OrderProduct

```
OrderProduct.joins(:product).where("products.name = ?", "Widget").map(&:customer_id)
```

Answer (score 1):

Rails associations are rich, you must be able to do, Product.find_by_name("widget").customers, to return all customers that ordered that product. If you want the first customer, call .first on it. (typing from mobile, so no proper indents)

Comment: yeah, this seems like the proper way to go about it

Comment: Actually, the real right way is to write a method in product class called, ordered_customers(name), and pass "widget" to it. Go OOPS!!

Answer (score 0):

This *should* work (untested tho)

`Customer.include(:products).where('product.name = ?', 'Widget').first`

Comment: Correction: Customer.includes(:products).where('products.name = ?', 'Widget').map(&:id). But It is a slow query.

Comment: Better: Customer.joins(:products).where('products.name = ?', 'Widget').map(&:id)

Comment: true. not sure about the performance implication of the query. OP would need to actually check created query for that.